# How do I find a right flash not to get red eyes?

Tags: flash, red-eye

How do I find a right flash not to get red eyes?
I did try all options.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Red-eye is caused by having the flash coming from close to the camera - if you move the flash off-camera or bounce it off something, you shouldn't get red-eye.

Answer (score 2):

Red eye is caused by the flash being to close to the optical axis of the photo.  The way to remove red eye is to move the flash away from the lens.  This can either be done by bouncing the flash off a wall/ceiling or by physically moving the flash using a cable or a wireless remote trigger device.

I've not seen this with an external flash unit however and there's not really a lot you can do to the pop-up with out killing what little power it has.  Maybe try a bit of card to bounce it off a wall?